# Something interrupts the WebSocket connection

Tags: javascript, websocket

Connection is interrupted after first sent bunch of data. I have another JavaScript that works fine with the server part but this piece of code causes error:

> WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED

Any ideas?

**JavaScript**

```
window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
var webSocket;
var stage;
var players = [];
var shapes = [];
var userMarker;
var messageNumber = 0;
var userPosition;
var prevUserPosition;

function start(){
    writeToScreen("Start");
    webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.34:8080/WaterWorldGame/game_endpoint");

    webSocket.onopen = function(event) {
     onOpen(event);
    };

    webSocket.onerror = function(event) {
       onError(event);
    };

    webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
       onMessage(event);
    };

    webSocket.onclose = function(event) {
        onClose(event);
    };

    stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");
    createjs.MotionGuidePlugin.install();
    userMarker = new createjs.Shape();
    userMarker.graphics.beginFill("DeepSkyBlue").drawCircle(0, 0, 3);
    userMarker.x = -100;
    userMarker.y = -100;
    stage.on("stagemousedown", function(evt) {
    if (userMarker.x == -100 && userMarker.y == -100) {
        userMarker.x = evt.stageX;;
        userMarker.y = evt.stageY;
        stage.addChild(userMarker);
        stage.update();
    } else {
        createjs.Tween.get(userMarker, {override:true})
        .to({x:stage.mouseX, y:stage.mouseY}, 4000);
        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(20); 
    }       
    }); 
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", locate);   
}   

function onOpen(event){
    writeToScreen("Connection established");
}

function onClose(event){
    writeToScreen("The connection was interrupted T.T");
}

function onMessage(event){
    var json = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var isExist = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if ( players[i] == json.playerName ) {
            shape = shapes[i];
            shape.x = json.x;
            shape.y = json.y;
            isExist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isExist == false)
    {
        players[players.length] = json.playerName;
        shapes[shapes.length] = new createjs.Shape();
        shape = shapes[shapes.length - 1];
        shape.graphics.beginFill("#555555").drawCircle(json.x, json.y, 3);
        stage.addChild(shape);
    }

    writeToScreen("Player: " + json.sessionName + "; x = " + json.x + "; y = " + json.y);
}

function onError(event){
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + event.data);
}   

function writeToScreen(message) {
    document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML += message + "<br>";
    messageNumber++;
    if (messageNumber == 20){
        document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = "";
        messageNumber = 0;
    }

}       

function doSend(){
    if (userPosition != undefined && userPosition != prevUserPosition)
    {
        writeToScreen("SENT: " + userPosition);
        webSocket.send(userPosition);
        prevUserPosition = userPosition;
    }
}

function locate(event) {
   stage.update();
   userPosition = '{'
               + '"x" : ' + userMarker.x
               + ', "y" : ' + userMarker.y
               + '}';
   doSend();    
}
```

Comment: It could be that the log you are referring to is caused by the doSend method attempting to send data through a closed socket. That's not the relevant log. Try reviewing the websocket frames log (it's not in the console) and post that error message.

Comment: How to select the frame to see the log when I open this tab it always only contains only "Select frame to browse its content"?

Comment: This is a the right place to find the error message. Try refreshing the page with the inspector open, than re-initiate the websocket connection (maybe that happen automatically on page load and maybe not). Make sure to select the connection you're reviewing on the left column. Select the Headers tab to see if the handshake passed and read what happened at that point. Select the Frames tab to see if any frames were sent or received. Select any frame under the "Frames" tab to read what happened with it...

Comment: P.S. This one drove me nuts at first, but **you might need to resize the list, by dragging down the borderline under the table's headers for the actual list to show**... it seems the list's original height is zero (0) and you need to resize it. I found this out by mistake (the mouse changes pointers).

Comment: I had exact same problem as cadmy and Myst's solution worked! The list has zero height until you drag down the border to show it.

Comment: OH MY GOD @Myst I JUST THOUGHT MY BROWSER HAD OPAQUE WEBSOCKETS ALL THIS TIME.